# Django migration error in heroku postgres

Tags: django, heroku, django-migrations

I've just deployed my Django website on Heroku and while running the command to make migrations it shows a lot of migrations to apply but when I try to migrate it, it says no migrations to apply.
Here's a photo of it.
[image]

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Don't run `makemigrations` on Heroku. By the time your code is deployed there this command shouldn't do anything as your models and your migrations should be synced up. Make migrations _locally_, commit the migration files, and run `migrate` both locally and on Heroku.

Comment: I'm using the default database of Django for local tests and I'm using the Heroku PostgreSQL for the production website.

Comment: The problem is already solved.  I had to  delete my database and migrate  things again

Comment: "I'm using the default database of Django for local tests and I'm using the Heroku PostgreSQL for the production website"—don't do that. Always use as close to the same software as possible in both development and production. Database engines aren't drop-in replacements for each other. I've seen real-world examples where something works fine with SQLite and then blows up in production with PostgreSQL. " I had to delete my database and migrate things again"—is that really a "solution"? In many cases your database will contain, you know, _data_.

Comment: Anyway, my point stands: don't run `makemigrations` on Heroku.

Comment: "is that really a "solution"? " since my database doesn't have any data stored yet, it works for now. But in the long run, I don't think that is a solution. And thanks for the suggestion. I'll use the same database for both development and production from now on